# OpenGL not rendering os x mavericks

Tags: opengl, osx-mavericks, glut

I'm trying to learn OpenGL with [this tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20In%20Review.html) I tried to do the coding in OS X Mavericks but the result is just a black window. I believe there should be a white triangle but don't know what I'm missing.

Here's the code

**glut_utils.h**

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>

void init();
void display();
void reshape (int w, int h);
void keyboard(uchar key, int x, int y);
```

**glut_utils.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "glut_utils.h"

GLuint CreateShader(GLenum eShaderType, const std::string &strShaderFile)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(eShaderType);
    const char *strFileData = strShaderFile.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &strFileData, NULL);

    glCompileShader(shader);

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar *strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);

        const char *strShaderType = NULL;
        switch(eShaderType)
        {
            case GL_VERTEX_SHADER: strShaderType = "vertex"; break;
            case GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER_EXT: strShaderType = "geometry"; break;
            case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER: strShaderType = "fragment"; break;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Compile failure in %s shader:\n%s\n", strShaderType, strInfoLog);
        delete[] strInfoLog;
    }

    return shader;
}

GLuint CreateProgram(const std::vector<GLuint> &shaderList)
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    for(size_t iLoop = 0; iLoop < shaderList.size(); iLoop++)
        glAttachShader(program, shaderList[iLoop]);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv (program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar *strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Linker failure: %s\n", strInfoLog);
        delete[] strInfoLog;
    }

    for(size_t iLoop = 0; iLoop < shaderList.size(); iLoop++)
        glDetachShader(program, shaderList[iLoop]);

    return program;
}

GLuint theProgram;

const std::string strVertexShader(
    "#version 330\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n"
);

const std::string strFragmentShader(
    "#version 330\n"
    "out vec4 outputColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n"
);

void InitializeProgram()
{
    std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;

    shaderList.push_back(CreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, strVertexShader));
    shaderList.push_back(CreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, strFragmentShader));

    theProgram = CreateProgram(shaderList);

    std::for_each(shaderList.begin(), shaderList.end(), glDeleteShader);
}

const float vertexPositions[] = {
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

GLuint positionBufferObject;
GLuint vao;

void InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

//Called after the window and OpenGL are initialized. Called exactly once, before the main loop.
void init()
{
    InitializeProgram();
    InitializeVertexBuffer();

    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(vao);
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(theProgram);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 27:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            return;
    }

}
```

**Tut01.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"
#include "glut_utils.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);

    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello Triangle");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the core profile header first:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Remove the `APPLE` suffix from `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE` and `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE` - they shouldn't be defined with the `gl3.h` header anyway.

Comment: After including `gl3.h` I was able to use `glGenVertexArrays` without the suffix `APPLE` which I guess was giving the problem. Now the question is what do those functionAPPLE mean? And why is it `gl3.h`the core profile? Is it because that is the version when OpenGL splitter into core and compatibility?

Comment: The functions have the `APPLE` at the end because they were part of an OpenGL extension. That functionality became standard with OpenGL 3.0. So once you include the right header, you can use their standard version. The core profile was established with 3.2.

Comment: An so, when I include `gl.h` I'm including Apple's extensions only? So far I know that Mavericks has support for OpenGL 4.1, how can I use the core profile of that?

Comment: Reading a bit more over the internet, I found that `gl3.h` contains all the declarations for the functions from OpenGL 3.2 onwards, i.e. should contain OpenGL 4.1 as implemented by Apple. Am I right?